# How to replace foreign reference in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key, constraint, alter-table

Suppose I have a foreign reference column which is pointing to an item A, how do I change it to item B? I would like to modify all records whose foreign reference column is A to B.

Comment: Do you want to change the foreign key definition of the value of the reference column?

Comment: Please [edit] to clarify your question. You cannot "modify records" to change FK constraints. Do you want to identify all FK constraints pointing to a given column (in the whole DB) and make them point to a different column (in a different table)? And please *always* disclose your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 2):

Sample data,

```
CREATE TABLE foo ( a int UNIQUE, b int UNIQUE );
CREATE TABLE bar ( c int REFERENCES foo(a) );
```

Simple `ALTER` statement,

```
ALTER TABLE bar
  DROP CONSTRAINT bar_c_fkey,
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (c) REFERENCES foo(b);
```

And, that worked!

```
                Table "public.bar"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 c      | integer |           |          | 
Foreign-key constraints:
    "bar_c_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (c) REFERENCES foo(b)
```